# Evaluating the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}dz$ with Cauchy's theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I would like to show that

> $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}dz=\sin t$$
>   if $t>0$ and $C$ is the circle $|z|=3$.

I am pretty sure that I need to use Cauchy to do this because it is really similar to the format, $$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$$
Only, the $z^2$ is throwing me off.  Can I break this up into multiple integrals somehow?

Comment: You could split $1/(z^2-1)$ into partial fractions.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo.  I'm changing to + now.

Comment: You can still do partial fractions on $1/(z^2+1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that 
$$\dfrac{1}{z^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{-2i}\left(\dfrac{1}{z+i}-\dfrac{1}{z-i}\right)$$

**Edit:**
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}\ dz 
&= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\dfrac{1}{-2i}\dfrac{e^{zt}}{z+i}\ dz - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\dfrac{1}{-2i}\dfrac{e^{zt}}{z-i}\ dz \\
&= \dfrac{1}{-2i}\left(e^{-it}-e^{it}\right) \\
&= \sin t
\end{align}